# Add new line in image while writing on image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to write text on image, but my text have so many words and it is not fitting in single line. So I need to add the new line (some thing like wrap) on the image below is code I am using.

```
string strFileName = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Certificate\\" + CertificateName.ToString();
Bitmap bitMapImage = new Bitmap(strFileName);
Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
graphicImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
graphicImage.DrawString(strCourseName, new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 22, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.GrayText, new Point(280, 325));
string strDesImgName = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Certi\\certificate.jpg";
bitMapImage.Save(strDesImgName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
graphicImage.Dispose();
bitMapImage.Dispose();
```

can any body please suggest me, how I can insert the extra text on the next line.
Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically going to want to implement your own version of text line wrapping by calling your DrawString function twice.  Once to write the first line (partially truncated) and once to writing the remaining txt.  The point parameter you are passing into the DrawString function will have to incremented with the height of the font you are using.  See [Font Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.height.aspx).  If you are not using a [fixed width font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) it can more difficult to know the width of the string and where to split it.  This is because each character in a non fixed width font is a different width.  For this example I split the string on the 10th character you will have to experiment on what makes the most sense for your application.

```
graphicImage.DrawString(strCourseName, new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 22, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.GrayText, new Point(280, 325));
```

becomes

```
graphicImage.DrawString(strCourseName.Substring(0,10), new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 22, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.GrayText, new Point(280, 325));
graphicImage.DrawString(strCourseName.Substring(10), , new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 22, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.GrayText, new Point(280, 347));
```